# Meteor - MongoDb - How to get seconds remaining between current data time and future date time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to get seconds remaining between a current dataTime and future dateTime.

I am using Meteor + MongoDb.

In Mongo DataTime is saved like this:

```
2015-12-11T06:14:39.671Z
```

I want seconds remaining between current datatime and future or expiry datetime.

Answer (score 1):

keep your time data in `epoch` format which is basically storing data in milliseconds. then you'll be easy able to compare using `momentJS` or substracting. And in `MongoDB` , this data will be stored as `Number` type not `Date`

```
var time= (new Date).getTime();
```

this piece of code will return time in milliseconds.

Comment: But this will create problem while fetching records on the base of specific date

Comment: one thing to note is that this is still a `datetime`. if you want to fetch within specific date, you can convert your parameter into milliseconds. Actually it's the trade off which you want to choose. Otherwise you need to parse manually `mongo` date time format to compare between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript Date can handle the sample input as listed in your question. If that format is consistant, the following should get you your answer:

```
var difference = (new Date(databaseDate).getTime()-Date.now())/1000;
```

Where Date.getTime() and Date.now() are in milliseconds (hence the 1000).